# Sequence contains no elements when using count on LINQ Query

Tags: linq, sequences

```
IEnumerable<EntityReference> children = (
    from c in OrgContext.CreateQuery<Account>()
    where
        c.ParentAccountId != null && c.ParentAccountId.Id.Equals(parentGuid)
    select 
        c.ToEntityReference()).ToList();

return children.Count() > 0 ? null : new List<EntityReference>();
```

Throws a "Sequence contains no elements" error. How can I reliably check if the sequence is empty before trying to count the elements? (I'd expect Count to simply return 0)

Comment: `ToList` _creates_ an empty list if the query returned no elements, therefore `children.Count()` can never raise that exception, so the reason for the error must be somewhere in _"(... my query ...)"_.

Comment: Can you post your query? I suspect there is a `First` or `Single` somewhere there...

Comment: As an aside, why do you create a `List<Account>` from a query if you just want to know if there is at least one element? It seems that you are throwing away the result anyway.

Comment: `return (my query).Any() ? null : new List<EntityReference>()` should work unless there is something wrong inside (my query).

Comment: I have amended the question to show the query. I don't know why, but call to c.ToEntityReference() was causing the problems. I worked around it by creating a new Account(){} with the properties from the query

Answer (score 1):

This error for me was caused by visual studio using an old build instead of my current build. I don't know why it does this, but I've had it happen in visual studio 2012 and 2013. Just deleting the bin folder fixed it.

In your case, I think the problem is that you're using the Count() method instead of the Count property.