# "System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements" is sometimes thrown

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a method that fails approximately 1 time out of 100:

```
 public int GetNbOfUploads()
    {
        using (EFDbContext eFDbContext = new EFDbContext())
        {
            return eFDbContext.RawDataUploads.Count();
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression) 
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression) 
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

I don't understand why I sometimes get this error. ? I cannot see any pattern when it occurs. It seems to be independent from the number of entries in the 'RawDataUploads' table. Also when there are no elements it mostly returns an answer without throwing an exception

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925869/sequence-contains-no-elements-when-using-count-on-linq-query help?

Comment: Where do you call *Single()*?

Comment: @ibrahimozgon, the stack trace shows that the call to`Count` internally leads to a call to `Single`.

Comment: I'm not sure but it may occur because of your relations. How about your RawDataUploads property? Does it have a required relation and it doesn't exist in DB. Because *Single* throws an exception when there is no element.